# Why can’t one develop apps on a mobile platform?

Tags: xcode

I would like to try to create iPhone apps on an actual iPhone. Why isn’t this supported by Apple?

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic as it can only be opinion-based. You might have luck rephrasing your question to be around something factual. However, if you have a genuine interest in the answer, it seems very likely that developers would find it hugely impractical to do development on an iPhone. Therefore it is not something companies making software for developers are focusing on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’m putting a hold on this since we don’t allow questions asking _why_ Apple does something X. If you can rephrase this to be something more specific or practical like using a specific tool, or overcoming a specific Xcode issue we can review the hold. If I mis-interpreted what you’re asking, please refine this to show your research and we can review the “unclear” or “too broad” close reasons as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this will be considered off-topic for the site, but nevertheless…

As it currently exists, Xcode is completely incompatible with iOS. Presumably at some in the future there will be some way to develop at least with Swift on iOS.

The only real answer is, of course, that no one who knows the answer to this *can* or *will* say, so there can be no real answer to this other than "Xcode doesn't run on iOS" which doesn't explain *why* Apple hasn't made it possible to develop for iOS on iOS before now.

Comment: Great quick explanation. Also, there’s no reason why people can’t write code or a book on an iPhone. The literal constraints of screen size, storage space are clear impediments to even getting playgrounds on a watch or phone if you try using IDE on an iPad. The phone is fine for writing - especially with an external keyboard, but editing / reviewing is a challenge even for prose let alone non-trivial code merges, etc...